# Avoid "Variable Assignment" log event creation

Tags: apex, developer-console, debug, eventlogfile

Due to Salesforce logsize limit (250 MB) I have to reduce the log file issued from one of our process in the org. 
After a lot of code-optimization and removing all useless statements the logfile is still big enough to reach the limit.

I noticed that most of the payload in the logfile seems to be provided from "variable assignment" event so my question is, can I avoid this writing during the code running (process launched from dev. console from Anonymous window).
I also want to avoid debug level modification if possible

To be clear, I don't want to prevent the event itself but the event writing in the log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

unfortunately without changing debug level `VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT` event will be displayed at `FINEST` Apex code debug level. (according to [Debug Log Levels](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_setting_debug_log_levels.htm&type=5))

so, set debug level to `FINER` or less

---

**event name:** VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT

**field or information logged with event:** Line number, variable name (including the variable’s namespace, if applicable), a string representation of the variable’s value, and the variable’s address

**category:** Apex Code

**level logged:** FINEST

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I  guessed that there was some limitation but I tryed to know if any exotic solution exists